# AngulaJS ui-router: routing to url state

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to write a really small app, that all it does it gets data from a external service, the external service accepts a path and return the files and directories in that path, think of it as a file browser. Everything was working fine when using `ngRoute` but I am trying to converting to `ui.router` since I have to update multiple sections of the page. The issue come from the fact that my paths don't seem to be working as I am always redirected to the `base` state, I assume because of the `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');`

I am extremely new to javascript and AngularJS and I've spent quite a few days trying to find a solution to this issue without much luck, all documentation I see always use a static url like `/demo/{id}/{info}` where my url is dynamic `/repos/{path}` where path is an actually path like `/tmp/test/test1/test2`

This is the current code

```
var app = angular.module("atlas", ['ui.router', 'repoControllers']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
  function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
    .state('base', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
          '': { templateUrl: 'partials/repo-list.html' },
          'repoinfo': { templateUrl: 'partials/repo-info.html' },
          'repoownership': { templateUrl: 'partials/group-ownership.html' },
          'repotype': { templateUrl: 'partials/repo-type.html' },
          'repopath': { templateUrl: 'partials/repo-path.html' },
          'userinfo': { templateUrl: 'partials/user-info.html' }
        },
        controller: 'RepoController'
      })
    .state('base.repos', {
        url: '/repos/*path',
        parent: 'base',
        views: {
          '': { templateUrl: 'partials/repo-list.html' },
          'repoinfo': { templateUrl: 'partials/repo-info.html' },
          'repoownership': { templateUrl: 'partials/group-ownership.html' },
          'repotype': { templateUrl: 'partials/repo-type.html' },
          'repopath': { templateUrl: 'partials/repo-path.html' },
          'userinfo': { templateUrl: 'partials/user-info.html' }
        },
        controller: 'RepoListCtrl'
      })
  }]);

app.factory('atlasRepository', function($http) {
    return {
      getIndex: function(path) {
        console.log("FACTORY: getIndex " + path);
        var sanitized = "";
        if (typeof path === 'undefined') {
          sanitized = '/';
        } else {
          sanitized = "/" + path.replace(/\/+/g, '/');
        };

        var url = "http://localhost:8080" + sanitized;
        console.log(url);
        return $http.get(url);
      }
    };
  });

app.controller("RepoController", function($scope, $stateParams, atlasRepository) {
    $scope.repos = atlasRepository.getIndex($stateParams.path).success(function(repos) {
        $scope.repos = repos;
        console.log("RepoController");
      });

  });


var repoControllers = angular.module('repoControllers', []);

repoControllers.controller("RepoListCtrl", function($scope, $stateParams, atlasRepository) {
    $scope.repos = atlasRepository.getIndex($stateParams.path).success(function(repos) {
        $scope.repos = repos;
        console.log($stateParams);
        console.log($scope);
      });

  });
app.filter('bytes', function() {
    return function(bytes, precision) {
      if (isNaN(parseFloat(bytes)) || !isFinite(bytes)) return '-';
      if (typeof precision === 'undefined') precision = 1;
      var units = ['bytes', 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB'],
      number = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024));
      return (bytes / Math.pow(1024, Math.floor(number))).toFixed(precision) +  ' ' + units[number];
    }
  });

app.filter('path', function() {
    return function(path) {
      path = path.replace(/^\//, '');
      return path;
    }
  });
```

and the partial view for the table listing the files/directories

```
 <table>
    <tr>
      <th>File Name</th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>Modified Date</th>
      <th>User</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="directory in repos.directories">
      <td><a href="#/repos/{{repos.path| path}}{{directory.name}}/"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> {{directory.name}}</a></td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td> {{directory.updatedat | date:"medium"}}</td>
      <td>unknown</td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></td>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="file in repos.files">
      <td><i class="fa fa-file"></i> {{file.name}}</td>
      <td> {{file.size | bytes}}</td>
      <td> {{file.updatedat| date:"medium"}}</td>
      <td>unknown</td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

I've tried using `ui-sref` in the template but once again all documentation points to fairly simple use cases `<a ui-sref="contacts.detail({ id: contact.id })">{{ contact.name }}</a>` which in my case does not work because I need to pass the current path plus the name of the directory to change to I have tried `<a ui-sref="contacts.detail({ id: repos.path + directory.name })">{{ directory.name }}</a>` with no luck, specially since the repos.path needs to be filtered

Comment: In your `ui-sref` example you have `contacts.detail(...)` is that how it actually is in your code or ...?

Comment: my code, or what I tried without luck was `<a ui-sref="base.repos({ path: repos.path + directory.name })">{{ directory.name }}</a>`

Comment: Can't you call a function on the `repos.path` and have that do the filter for you by injecting the `$filter` service into your controller? i.e. `<a ui-sref="base.repos({ path: filterPath(repos.path) + directory.name })">{{ directory.name }}</a>`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably with your state definition. According to the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/url-routing#regex-parameters), wildcards should be specified as:

```
    .state('base.repos', {
        url: '/repos/{path:.*}',
        parent: 'base',
        views: {
          '': { templateUrl: 'partials/repo-list.html' },
          'repoinfo': { templateUrl: 'partials/repo-info.html' },
          'repoownership': { templateUrl: 'partials/group-ownership.html' },
          'repotype': { templateUrl: 'partials/repo-type.html' },
          'repopath': { templateUrl: 'partials/repo-path.html' },
          'userinfo': { templateUrl: 'partials/user-info.html' }
        },
        controller: 'RepoListCtrl'
      })
```

Comment: According to the documentation they are both valid '/files/{path:.*}' - Matches any URL starting with '/files/' and captures the rest of the path into the parameter 'path'.
'/files/*path' - Ditto. Special syntax for catch all.

Comment: True... didn't even notice that example.

Answer (score 0):

First observation: both your default ('') state views specify the same templateUrl. That means you will be displaying the same template for both your urls. I realise, however that you specified 'redirected'.

Second observation: your 'otherwise' function is being run before your state routing. That might mean your otherwise is being given matched before your state routing is, which would result in the same issue. I could be wrong about this.

Comment: the templateUrl section is done on purpose the `/` url shows the "root" file system, while the `/repos/*path` url shows the files inside the "path", you may also notice that the `RepoController` and the `RepoListCtrl` are identical.